# block controller method until db get result

Tags: playframework

I would like to create method in controlller which will wait until I fetched a correct data from database..
I know that I should use a Promise byt I dont know how to force this promise to wait for db record.

I want to do someting like this:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> getData(long userId) {

getIngormationFromDb();
while(informationFetched){
    return F.Promise.pure(ok(multimediaJSON));
    if(duration > 10 seconds) {
        return F.Promise.pure(badRequest());
    } 
}
}
```

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

Answer (score 2):

The following code would work as you want however the action will be blocked during it execution:

```
public static Promise<Result> getData(long userId) {
    try {
        return promise(() -> {
            return getIngormationFromDb();
        }).map(ingormationFromDbResult -> {
            return ok(ingormationFromDbResult);
        }).get(10_000);
    } catch (F.PromiseTimeoutException e) {
        return Promise.pure(badRequest());
    }
}
```

So, it is recommended to execute blocking code in the separate execution context (timeout should be controlled on the client side):

```
public static Promise<Result> getData(long userId) {
    return promise(() -> {
        return getIngormationFromDb();
    }, separateExecutionContext).map(ingormationFromDbResult -> {
        return ok(ingormationFromDbResult);
    });
}
```

You can find more details in the documenation here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

Comment: i used  
    Promise<Result> prom = Promise.delayed(() -> {
        return ok(json or something } , 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);